# What endpoint would be suitable for answering a question in REST design

Tags: rest, http, server

What endpoint would be suitable for answering a question.

I thought using

```
 post /questions/{id}
```

It's not self explanatory. Using posting to "/question/2" is hard to imagine that it is answering a question.

I thought about using

```
 post  /questions/{id}/answers
```

Question and answers do not map to models or tables in my system, if that is relevant. I use another api to access the question. My application is serving as a hub.

Comment: Could you clarify? Are you designing the back end and asking about how to set up the endpoints? Or are you trying to call an existing API (like Stackoverflow) and asking how to do it?

Comment: In a system that follows the REST architecture model, the actual characters used in a URI are not of relevance to a client as it shouldn't parse the URI or deduce some knowledge from the URI. As REST is just a generalization of the Web, the same concepts can and should be used that you are used to in the Web as well. Just look at SO i.e, does the URI tell you anything about answers to questions? No, though there might be answers available. What's more important though is that you use standards, i.e. like media types, links and link relations (HATEOAS) and teach clients what to do through forms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

REST doesn't care what spelling you use for your URI.  `/cbcaf573-4f34-40ae-a91b-f097adfac495` is a perfectly satisfactory URI.  The various spelling conventions that you see should have roughly the same weight as variable naming in your local coding standard; it may make it easier for people to understand what is going on, but the machines don't care.

What you do normally want to pay some attention to: which resource's representation is going to *change* as a consequence of the request.  If the representation of `/questions/{id}` is normally going to include all of the answers in it, then you'll normally want to POST the answer to `questions/{id}`.  If the representation of the question just includes a link to answers, then you'll normally want to POST to the same URI as the link.

The motivation for this is that HTTP's [cache invalidation rules](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7234#section-4.4) are all based on the target uri of the unsafe request.

Using the cache invalidation style isn't required, however.  For example, on this question here: it's URI is

`https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56349556/what-endpoint-would-be-suitable-for-answering-a-question-in-rest-design`

But when I submit an answer, the POST request with my form data is sent to

`https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56349556/answer/submit`

And on successful save of my answer, I get a client side redirect to

`https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56349556/what-endpoint-would-be-suitable-for-answering-a-question-in-rest-design/56350857#56350857`

And that works too - my browser doesn't have any trouble figuring out how to create the requests that it needs to follow the submission protocol.

Comment: So, I don't need to be perfectionist about how endpoints are going to be named. I thought that a very hard rule existed.

Comment: @DiegoAlves There is this myth around that URIs must not contain verbs as the verb is expressed through the HTTP operation but as both clients and server shouldn't interpret URIs this doesn't make any sense. Moreover, all "usable" URIs should be returned by the server anyway and not be madeup by the client. Some even state that there is this concept of a RESTful URI (which does not exist) that somehow expresses the intent of the resource. This is actually dangerous as this might lead to clients implementing the response format of the endpoint into the client, which might fail on changes though